# Making the /prestashop/ part of the url invisible

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop, front-controller

I've recently built a shop using prestashop and the production install of prestashop is in a subdirectory on the server called /prestashop. What I want to do is make it so that you don't have to go to http://mydomain.com/prestashop to view the website but rather just http://mydomain.com

There are two ways I've thought of so far, I could move prestashop's front controller in the index file to the root, similar to what is done in wordpress, although I'm not sure if this is a viable option as I'm not experienced enough to mess around with it. Here's the code of index.php for all those interested:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();
```

The second option is to use apache's mod_rewrite module so you have something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$   /prestashop/$1
```

But I open the htaccess file already there and this code is there, so I don't know if this can be edited or not:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/prestashop/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'll keep on playing around and trying to figure it out myself, but any help from you guys would be very greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you redirect with `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$   /prestashop/$1` or any similar rule, you won't be able to access the root directory. ¿Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I just want the users to go straight to mydomain.com/prestashop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Prestashop will figure out the paths correctly, but try changing your index.php file to:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/prestashop/config/config.inc.php');
Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();
```

I'd avoid using .htaccess for this if possible since its just more overhead to incur by doing more rewrites on each request.

Basically all this does is modify the front controller code to look in the correct directory (/prestashop) for the configuration.  It shouldn't be a problem for it.

EDIT:  You'll also need to move the .htaccess file from /prestashop/.htaccess to /.htaccess so the rewrites for URLs still work.

Comment: When I do this it still redirects to /prestashop/, maybe this is due to existing code in the .htaccess file?

Comment: It might be PHP code in Prestashop doing it.  Is there a setting that defines the site URL in config file or admin?  If so try changing it to yourdomain.com instead of yourdomain.com/prestashop

Comment: There was a setting that had "base uri", changed it to /, now all my css and images are broken, but you solved it anyways! :D Thanks man

Comment: You'll probably have to move all the prestashop assets from /prestashop/css, /prestashop/images etc to /css and /images to fix that.  Otherwise, glad that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Following the instruction/hint from michaeld at http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/18393-solved-move-prestashop-from-subfolder-to-root/

I figured out that it works!

In addition, if you use PrestaShop media servers, please add the rewrite, too.

Here's the complete .htaccess that works for me:

```
# Copy and paste the following code into the .htaccess file
# in the public_html folder of your hosting account
# make the changes to the file according to the instructions.

# Do not change this line - RewriteEngine on
RewriteEngine on

# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$

# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/

# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1

# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]


# For PrestaShop Media server #1 
# Change mediaserver1.yourdomain.com to be your media server subdomain
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mediaserver1.yourdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1

# For PrestaShop Media server #2
# Change mediaserver2.yourdomain.com to be your media server subdomain
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mediaserver2.yourdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1


# For PrestaShop Media server #3
# Change mediaserver3.yourdomain.com to be your media server subdomain
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mediaserver3.yourdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
```

PS: Make sure that you set Physical URL on PrestaShop BO to "/"

Comment: I like this method but... I notice that, when navigating to the Back Office some url setting like invoice got the subfolder url. some are not like the Dashboard is ok.